# Suspend & sleep freeze issue

Tags: suspend

After installing elementary OS, I have noticed that whenever the laptop goes into sleep it freezes. Also while trying to click the suspend button, the system just freezes. Please help on the issue as every time I will have to force turn off the system.

Update: 08/11:
Laptop Lenovo Z51- 70
i7 5th Gen, 16gn RAM, 1TB HDD, 128 GB SSD, Graphics Radeon R9 M375.

Comment: Yes,I have the same..so I turned off all battery saving options..Going to sleep, hibernating etc all are turned off

Comment: Please add more information about your laptop (model, hardware, etc)

Comment: @Marko Thanks. Even i was thinking of same.

Comment: @Maccer. Thanks for the response. I have updated the laptop information.